# Converting a Go-To Statement from Fortran 77 to Python

Tags: python, fortran, fortran77

I have the following FORTRAN Code which I want to rewrite in Python:

```
2 continue
 statement 1
 statement 2

 do 1 j=1, 10
 statement 3
 statement 4
1 continue

 if a .lt. 5 go to 2
```

Does anyone have an elegant way of implementing this structure in python?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions and add a specific version when necessary.

Comment: Just use a loop with an `exit` statement (see your textbook or manual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using something similar to the following:

```
while True:
  statement 1
  statement 2
  for i in range(1,11):
    statement 3
    statement 4
  if a >= 5:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

The transformation can be straightforward. Here I am assuming that you can change 'a' at the beginning so that the 'while' condition is satisfied initially. Something like

```
a = 0
while a < 5:
    statement 1
    statement 2
    # 'do 1 j=1, 10' will include 10, right? Not so in Python
    for i in range(1, 11):
        statement 3
        statement 4
```

Comment: The initial `a=0` isn't supported by the original code fragment?  I'm not familiar with the syntax of Python, but (ignoring the initial setting), doesn't this allow a zero-trip loop, in contrast to the original?  [Admittedly, that's covered by your introductory sentence, but...]

Comment: It doesn't allow a zero-trip loop. If a is 0, it is < 5! But if a already has a value, before the 'while', we probably shouldn't change it. If so, I would go for the 'while True' solution above.

Comment: Yes, my "concern" is about the `a=0`.  Clearly stating that as an assumption of yours (the question isn't clear on that aspect), and perhaps noting the implication as you comment, would make that concern vanish.